# Add date stamp to multiple text files in a directory using bat script

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory with a bunch of text files named like this:

test_00.txt 
test_01.txt 
test_02.txt

There can be up to 100 files named like this although the amount is always changing. I want to rename all the files with a datestamp like this:

test_00_23032016 
test_01_23032016 
test_02_23032016

So far the only way I have found to do this is by copying one line of code over 100 times and I figure there must be a better way to do this?

My code:

```
    ren test_00.txt test_00_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt
    ren test_01.txt test_01_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt
    ren test_02.txt test_02_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt
```

Comment: what is the max number of files?If the format is like the given it would be 99.

Comment: Do you really want the current date to be used, or would you like the datestamp to reflect the modification/creation date of every file?

Comment: Actually this would probably be a better practice then what I have asked for. Do you have an example script which would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, provided the maximum number is 99 and the minimal number is 00

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (0,1,99) do (
    set "number=0%%i"
    set "number=!number:~-2!"
    if exist "test_!number!.txt" ren "test_!number!.txt" "test_!number!_!date:~-10,2!!date:~-7,2!!date:~-4,4!.txt"
)
```